# C++ template types nested in a template class definition

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I've a situation where there is a class definition that looks like this:

```
template<class T>
class Alpha< Bravo<T> >
{
....
};
```

I'm compiling with gnu g++ and the compiler is complaining that Alpha is, "is not a template".

I've seen this same technique used in the library that Bravo was written in and Bravo is a templated class. Am I missing something? I've stripped Alpha down to the bone and done testing with no compilation success. I've also tried to copy+paste code from the place I saw this working in Bravo's library and same thing, no success, same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should accept the answer below that you liked... flags the question as answered from the list view. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have there is a partial template specialization; however, any template specialization needs a *primary* template to specialize, and *that* you do not have.

```
template<class T>
class Alpha;

template<class T>
class Alpha<Bravo<T> >
{
    // ...
};
```

Comment: awesome works like a champ! It also makes a lot more sense using a forward declaration. I was getting confused by the syntax. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare a primary template first. What you've written is a specialization.

```
//primary template - the definition is optional
template<class T>
class Alpha
{
};

//specialization
template<class T>
class Alpha< Bravo<T> >
{
};
```